# Toggle column stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to click a button and toggle series on and off. I do not understand why, but my button's HTML is showing a function and and not its attributes:

```
$button.click(function() {
    alert($('#button').text);

    if ($button.text == 'Show previous years')
    {
        for (var i=0;i<chart.series.length;i++)
        {
            if (chart.series[i].name.indexOf("13/14")== false)
            {
                chart.series[i].show();
            }
            alert($button.html);
            $button.html('Hide previous years');
        }
    } else {
            for (var i=0;i<chart.series.length;i++)
            {
                if (chart.series[i].name.indexOf("13/14")>0)
                {
                    chart.series[i].show();
                }
                $button.html('Show previous years');
            }
    }
});
```

Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/pzh20/6cQ2N/8/

Comment: At the beginning in this line: if ($button.text == 'Show previous years'), you dont go there, always else is running. So maybe it is a first clue, why it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.text` which is a function.

Replace `.text` by `.text()` and it will be the `text()`'s return value, which is the string you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/6cQ2N/9/

In this edited fiddle, you'll get a good alert value since I changed the `.text` to `.text()`

Comment: Indeed, since `text` is not a property but a function, you will have to to add `()` at the end. The same rule also applies to `html()`. One more thing, `indexOf()` returns a 0-based index or -1 if not found. Therefore, the condition `chart.series[i].name.indexOf("13/14") == false` is never valid.